# Why is int type error? TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I got an error,
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method .
Traceback is like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    wavdata = wav[z:q]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

My code is

```
#coding:utf-8
import wave
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def wavread(filename):
    wf = wave.open(filename, "r")
    fs = wf.getframerate()
    x = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
    x = np.frombuffer(x, dtype="int16") / 32768.0  # (-1, 1)に正規化
    wf.close()
    return x, float(fs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wav, fs = wavread("3_7_9.wav")
    t = np.arange(0.0, len(wav) / fs, 1/fs)

    center = len(wav) // 2  
    cuttime = 0.04         
    z = center-cuttime // 2*fs
    q= center + cuttime // 2*fs
    wavdata = wav[z:q]
    time = t[z:q]

    plot(time * 1000, wavdata)
    xlabel("time [ms]")
    ylabel("amplitude")
    savefig("waveform.png")
    show()
```

I think variable of center & z & q is int type, so I really cannot understand why this error happen.First,I wrote this part like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wav, fs = wavread("3_7_9.wav")
    t = np.arange(0.0, len(wav) / fs, 1/fs)

    center = len(wav) / 2  
    cuttime = 0.04         
    z = center-cuttime / 2*fs
    q= center + cuttime / 2*fs
    wavdata = wav[z:q]
    time = t[z:q]

    plot(time * 1000, wavdata)
    xlabel("time [ms]")
    ylabel("amplitude")
    savefig("waveform.png")
    show()
```

so these division parts are not int type but float type,therefore I could understand why this error happen.But now I changed these part into //,so these parts is int.So,how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `z` and `q` are still `float`

```
center = len(wav) // 2  
cuttime = 0.04         
z = center - cuttime // 2 * fs
q = center + cuttime // 2 * fs
```

Because both `cuttime` and `fs` are `float`, so the whole expression becomes `float`.

You need to cast it to `int` like

```
z = int(center - cuttime // 2 * fs)
q = int(center + cuttime // 2 * fs)
```

Comment: `cuttime` being a float is not important here - `2.0 // 2` returns an `int`. The issue is the `fs`

Comment: @Eric But in my python3.5 `2.0 // 2` return `float`.

Comment: I take it back, my memory failed me. That strikes me as a possibly poor design choice in [PEP0238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), but I might be missing something

Comment: @Eric PEP0238 doesn't say anything about the type of the return value. `5.0 // 2` is `2.0` it is floored but it remains `float`.

Comment: Yes it does: _"the result type will be the common type into which `a` and `b` are coerced before the operation"_

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the problem stems from the fact that your variables `z` and `q` are floats. Make sure you cast them to `int`.